# Como funcionam o algoritmos de hash da família SHA?

Tags: algoritmo, hash, sha1

Gostaria de entender como funcionam os algoritmos de hash da família SHA ***(Secure Hash Algorithm)***, tais como o `SHA-1`, `SHA-2`, `SHA-3`, e entender as diferenças entre eles.

Procuro respostas didáticas, que me façam compreender os processos utilizados por estes algoritmos passo-a-passo, dando ênfase a parte lógica e matemática, e se possível, as operações com bits.

Note que não peço exemplos de código, embora sejam válidos para a explicação.

Comment: Que eu saiba, cada algoritmo de hash funciona de forma diferente (talvez haja alguma similaridade entre eles, mas não tenho certeza). A menos que você esteja buscando uma resposta bem alto nível, creio que seria melhor perguntar separadamente por algoritmo, ou a pergunta deve ficar muito ampla.

Comment: Fiz o que você sugeriu. Realmente, os algoritmos são diferentes. Dividi em duas perguntas, a outra pergunta se encontra disponível aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43495/como-funciona-o-algoritmo-de-hash-md5 A divisão fica até melhor para referências futuras.

Comment: Blz, mas só adiantando: o SHA-1 de fato tem relação com o SHA-2 (e o SHA-1 é semelhante ao MD5), mas o SHA-3 pelo que eu entendi é radicalmente diferente dos dois primeiros. A questão é que o nome "SHA" (bem como o nome "AES") foi dado ao vencedor de competições promovidas por agências governamentais americanas, que selecionam o melhor hash/cifra baseado numa série de critérios, para padronização. Ou seja, eles não vêm necessariamente dos mesmos autores, nem seguem a mesma lógica (inclusive o nome original do SHA-3 é "Keccak" e do AES é "Rijndael").

Comment: Pensava que a diferença entre eles não era tão grande assim, somente algumas melhorias "mágicas" entre um e outro. Bem, preciso compreender o passo-a-passo para fundamentá-los no meu trabalho de conclusão de curso. Eu já utilizei estes algoritmos algumas vezes, mas confesso que as operações que eles utilizam para efetuar a "mágica" me confunde um pouco. Principalmente as operações baixo nível.

Comment: hehe "um pouco"? Eu fico com dor-de-cabeça só de ler "hash" e "algoritmo" na mesma frase... :P O máximo que já consegui entender foi o RSA e olhe lá.

Comment: Confundem bastante, hahaha... Eu tentei entender o AES (Citado em uma outra pergunta), mas não fui muito feliz nos meus estudos até agora. Por este motivo pedi uma resposta "didática". Meu orientador disse que apenas fundamentar estes algoritmos no TCC não é suficiente, preciso entender o funcionamento deles. E de fato, concordo.

Comment: "Entender" em que nível? Criptografia é um domínio extremamente especializado, muito mais pro lado da matemática pura do que pra computação. Me parece excessivo para um simples TCC, não sei. Talvez alguém consiga quebrar os algoritmos em etapas e dar a ideia geral de cada uma, mas dizer **por que** cada etapa existe e o que ela representa, acho bastante improvável... Espero estar enganado, entretanto. Depois vou tentar escrever algo na pergunta do AES, e você avalia se é suficiente pra você ou não. Nos hashes, não vou nem arriscar.

Comment: Uma boa indrodução é o livro do Daniel Balparda de Carvalho - Criptografia Métodos e Algoritmos.Mas face a natureza da criptografia não espere encontrar material farto na Web.

Comment: @mgibsonbr preciso compreender a parte lógica e matemática. Não é necessário detalhamento do porque elas foram desenvolvidas de uma forma ou de outra. Esse nível de detalhamento daria uma dissertação de mestrado... preciso compreender os passos e como eles funcionam. As operações que acontecem, principalmente as que envolvem os trabalhos com bits. Não é necessário explicar as causas que tornam o algoritmo seguro, a importância do algoritmo, aplicações, nem coisas do gênero. Vou editar minhas perguntas em breve, no momento não posso fazê-lo.

Comment: @Motta agradeço pela indicação. Vou consultar o material que você indicou =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SHA1 [(Fonte)](http://johnnymarques.blogspot.com.br/2007/04/sha1-secure-hash-algoritm.html):

> O SHA1 implementa um algoritmo de hash sem chave, que pega uma
>   mensagem de até 264 bits e produz um resumo da mensagem de 160-bits e
>   é utilizado para a verificação de integridade da mensagem. Ele é
>   baseado nos princípios de projeto dos algoritmos de hash MD4 e MD5
>   (Memory Digest 4 e 5). O SHA1 é considerado o sucessor do MD5, um dos
>   primeiros e mais utilizado algoritmos de hash, processando
>   sequencialmente blocos de 512 bits. Cada processamento é feito por
>   bloco com cerca de 80 passos. SHA-1 e seu funcionamento A sua lógica
>   de funcionamento pode ser dividida em cinco passos:
>
> 1) Acrescentar bits de enchimento: toda mensagem terá bits
>   acrescentados, sendo o tamanho final modulo 512 congruente a 448.
>   Assim, uma mensagem pode ter de 1 a 512 bits de enchimento, que
>   consiste de um bit com valor 1 seguido de quantos bits 0 forem
>   necessários.
>
> 2) Acrescentar tamanho da mensagem: um bloco de 64 bits é acrescentado
>   à mensagem, sendo tratado como um inteiro sem sinal de 64-bit. Este
>   bloco contém o tamanho original da mensagem (antes do enchimento).
>
> 3) Inicialização do buffer MD: um buffer de 160 bits é utilizado para
>   manter os resultados intermediários e final da função de hash. Este
>   buffer pode ser representado como cinco registradores de 32 bits, que
>   são inicializados com o seguinte valor (em hexadecimal): A = 67 45 23
>   01 B = EF CD AB 89 C = 98 BA DC FE D = 10 32 54 76 E = C3 D2 E1 F0
>
> 4) Processamento da mensagem em blocos de 512 bits: o centro do
>   algoritmo é uma função de compressão que consiste de quatro iterações,
>   que possuem 20 passos cada. Estas iterações são similares, mas
>   utilizam uma estrutura lógica diferente.
>
> 5) Saída: depois de processar todos os blocos de 512 bits, a saída da
>   última iteração fornece o hash de 160 bits.

SHA2 ([Fonte](http://bdm.unb.br/bitstream/10483/6608/1/2013_GracielleForechiOlivier.pdf) ou [Fonte em Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OQO2Ubw2XI8J:bdm.unb.br/bitstream/10483/6608/1/2013_GracielleForechiOlivier.pdf%20&cd=7&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br)):

> O modelo dos algoritmos de SHA-2 segue a mesma estrutura adotada no algoritmo SHA-1. Da mesma forma, implementam funções de resumo iteradas, novamente seguindo o paradigma Merkle Damgard. Os valores de 224 e 384 correspondem aos valores de 256 e 512, sendo apenas um truncamento dos valores de saída.
>
> Por exemplo o SHA-256 processa, assim como no SHA-1, mensagens de valor máximo equivalente a 264 bits e também faz uso de palavras com 32 bits.
>
> A construção dos algoritmos de SHA-2 é muito semelhante à construção do algoritmo de SHA-1. As diferenças consistem no número de blocos,no número de rodadas das funções de compressão, o uso de deslocamentos de bits para esquerda e para a direita e no tamanho da constante que define as mensagens de entrada e saída do algoritmo. O SHA-256 processa mensagens com 264 bits e trabalha com palavras de 32 bits. A entrada da função de compressão possui 512 bits. Sua variável de estado contém 256 bits, que por sua vez, gera outra variável com 256 bits. Essas características são idênticas no algoritmo SHA-512, com as peculiaridades de tamanho,tais quais: mensagem de 2128 bits, as palavras de 64 bits e a entrada da função consiste de um bloco com 1024 bits.
>
> O preenchimento da mensagem no algoritmo de SHA-2 ocorre de forma análoga ao que acontece no algoritmo de SHA-1. Ou seja, sucintamente, acrescenta-se um bit 1,no final da mensagem, acrescenta-se 0 até que a palavra tenha o tamanho proporcional à quantidade de blocos, e por fim concatenar-se com bits para sinalizar o tamanho da mensagem ao último bloco. A computação do resumo inicia-se com a mensagem sendo dividida em blocos de 512 bits e a inicialização das variáveis de estado. Em seguida é realizada uma série de operações lógicas descritas por funções. Essas operações são deslocamentos, XOR(ou exclusivo), AND e NOT. Alguns desses algoritmos das família SHA-2 fazem uso das mesmas funções antes presentes na estrutura do algoritmo de SHA-1. A mensagem de 512 bits é dividida em 16 palavras, cada uma com 32 bits é expandida para 64 palavras de 32 bits. Posteriormente, para cada palavra é realizada uma rodada do algoritmo, mas uma particularidade do SHA-2 é que cada rodada é composta por uma constante diferente. Por fim, as variáveis de estados geradas inicialmente são somadas módulo 2 (XOR) com os valores resultante das rodadas.Em todos os algoritmos da família SHA-2, esses procedimentos são os mesmos, vari-ando tão somente os tamanhos de 32 bits para 64 bits para o blocos de mensagem.
>
> Na família de algoritmo SHA-2, as operações são simples e possuem bom desempenho. Entretanto, o algoritmo é fortemente sequencial, não permitindo fácil paralelização. Cada rodada do algoritmo somente pode ser computada antes de cada palavra com seus então 32 bits tendo sido calculados anteriormente. Isso requer uma sequência para realizara computação. O último bloco que contém o preenchimento para garantir que todos sejam múltiplos de 512 bits usa, como dito, as funções de preenchimento que hoje são implementadas em software que requerem custo mínimo de processamento.

SHA3 ([Fonte](http://bdm.unb.br/bitstream/10483/6608/1/2013_GracielleForechiOlivier.pdf) ou [Fonte em Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OQO2Ubw2XI8J:bdm.unb.br/bitstream/10483/6608/1/2013_GracielleForechiOlivier.pdf%20&cd=7&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br)):

> Esse algoritmo faz uso do paradigma esponja, composto por duas fases de processa-mento. A primeira delas divide a mensagem em blocos e os absorve em estados internos.Esses estados são originados a partir de um estado sendo inicializado com zeros e, em seguida, passa a ser iterado com rodadas que possuem cinco mapeamentos, que fazem a difusão e a distribuição dos elementos nos estados. Depois de finalizados, a função passa para a fase de esmagamento, que por sua vez intercala a aplicação das funções de mapeamento até que se tenha o número de bits que atende o tamanho da saída no nível de segurança escolhido.

Maiores informações contém nos links que deixei em cada algoritmo. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -5):

Secure Hash Algoritm (SHA)
Secure Hash Algorithms (em português, Algoritmos de Hash Seguro) são uma família de funções hash criptográficas publicadas pelo Instituto Nacional de Padrões e Tecnologia (NIST) como um Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) dos EUA. O SHA inclui algumas versões, o SHA-1 pega uma mensagem de até 264 bits e produz um resumo da mensagem de 160-bits e é utilizado para a verificação de integridade da mensagem.
SHA-2 é muito semelhante à construção do algoritmo de SHA-1. As diferenças consistem no número de blocos,no número de rodadas das funções de compressão, o uso de deslocamentos de bits para esquerda e para a direita e no tamanho da constante que define as mensagens de entrada e saída do algoritmo. SHA-3 Esse algoritmo faz uso do paradigma esponja, composto por duas fases de processamento. A primeira delas divide a mensagem em blocos e os absorve em estados internos.Esses estados são originados a partir de um estado sendo inicializado com zeros e, em seguida, passa a ser iterado com rodadas que possuem cinco mapeamentos, que fazem a difusão e a distribuição dos elementos nos estados. Depois de finalizados, a função passa para a fase de esmagamento, que por sua vez intercala a aplicação das funções de mapeamento até que se tenha o número de bits que atende o tamanho da saída no nível de segurança escolhido.

Comment: Uma cópia do Wikipédia sem formatação e sem citação de fonte não é uma boa resposta, além de ser plágio...